# Sort an array with respect to sorting of an another array iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, sorting

I have a situation here, I have two arrays,array1 and array2 and one tableview. I have loaded array1 to the table view. So here, I'm sorting array2, I've done that, but how can I sort array1 with respect to the change in array2 and to reload array1 in tableview. That is I need to sort array1 automatically when I sort array2.
Any ideas? Please share your thoughts. 
Thanks :)

Comment: And how to sorts depend from each other?

Comment: that is the problem here, both of the arrays are not connected each other. The content in the array2 is the dates, so I can sort this comparing to the NSDate. So, is there any way to arrange the rows in array1, with respect to the change in array2? I'm not sure, but if we consider the row number of both arrays? Any idea?

Comment: I got a method, - (void)replaceObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withObjects:(NSArray *)objects . Does it work?? If yes can you provide some sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical advice, would be that, if the objects are sorted together, then they're related somehow, and both pieces of data should conform a new object (A dictionary, an NSObject, whatever).

I mean, if array1 is `[1, 5, 4, 3, 2]` and array2 is `["hello", "world", "big", "little", "my"]`, then the mixed array would be:

`[(1, "hello"), (5, "world"), (4, "big"), (3, "little"), (2, "my")]`.

Sorting this is trivial, and it makes sense if the data is correlated (no way to tell since you didn't specify this).

## Objective-C example

Custom Object (CustomObject.h) that holds both name/number (using a number as a trivial example):

```
@interface CustomObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger number;

+ (id)customObjectWithName:(NSString*)name andNumber:(NSInteger)number;

@end
```

CustomObject.m:

```
#import "CustomObject.h"

@implementation CustomObject

@synthesize name, number;

+ (id)customObjectWithName:(NSString*)name andNumber:(NSInteger)number
{
    CustomObject *customObject = [[CustomObject alloc] init];

    customObject.name = name;
    customObject.number = number;

    return customObject;
}

- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(Number:%d, Name:%@)", self.number, self.name];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [name release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Using these objects together with sorting:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            [CustomObject customObjectWithName:@"Hello" andNumber:1], 
                            [CustomObject customObjectWithName:@"gentlemen?" andNumber:5], 
                            [CustomObject customObjectWithName:@"you" andNumber:4],
                            [CustomObject customObjectWithName:@"are" andNumber:3], 
                            [CustomObject customObjectWithName:@"how" andNumber:2],
                                nil];

[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    return [(CustomObject*)obj1 number] - [(CustomObject*)obj2 number];
}];

NSLog(@"Results: %@", array);
```

The output looks like:

```
2011-09-23 03:27:14.388 Test[5942:b303] Results: (
"(Number:1, Name:Hello)",
"(Number:2, Name:how)",
"(Number:3, Name:are)",
"(Number:4, Name:you)",
"(Number:5, Name:gentlemen?)"
```

Comment: Nice logic, I think this should work. You mean to load both the arrays into a dictionary with a keyvalue and do the sorting?

Comment: And your second opinion is good, if that is possible, would you provide any sample?

Comment: I'm still checking if the second option is possible. The first option means that both pieces of data belong to the same object, so you should consider grouping each individual pair of data together, what are you storing in these arrays?

Comment: In one array1 some string values and in array2 date. I think it would be better if it is possible to implement the second option. Looking forward to you, thanks.

Comment: I didn't find an easy way to achieve the second way, arrays are quite tricky underneath. I'll post an example for the first method.

Answer (score 0):

Would need more info (source code or psudo) to determine how/when/where the sorting of array2 takes place to answer how array1 can be sorted; but once array1 does get sorted, you can reload the values into the table with:

```
[myTable reloadData];
```

And it will reload each row and cell, reading array1's values in their sorted order.

Comment: in default when app launches, array1 should be loaded in the table. And when I click on sort button, need to sort array2 and when it finishes, sort array1 with respect to the changes in array2, and reload table.